# Distance filter not working as expected in standard location services

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am using standard location services to track location.

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.distanceFilter = DISTANCE_LIMIT //value set to 20
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

With the filter distance set, I assumed that the location updates would be received only when the user location changes by the specified distance. However, the updates were received for movements that were less than the preset distance value.

So I set up my delegate method as:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard locations.count > 0 else {
        return
    }

    guard let location = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    let previousLocationEncoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultKey.previousVisitedLocation) as? Data

    if previousLocationEncoded == nil {

        let encodedLocation = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: location)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedLocation, forKey: UserDefaultKey.previousVisitedLocation)

        // do some task

    } else {

        let previousLocationDecoded = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: previousLocationEncoded!) as! CLLocation

        let distanceBetweenVisits = previousLocationDecoded.distance(from: location)

        if distanceBetweenVisits > DISTANCE_LIMIT {

            // do some other task 

            let encodedLocation = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: location)

            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedLocation, forKey: UserDefaultKey.previousVisitedLocation)

        }
    }
}
```

The objective is to calculate the distance of current location from previously saved location to determine if the location has changed by the distance filter value.

However, sometimes, even if I am not moving, the condition ***distanceBetweenVisits > DISTANCE_LIMIT*** becomes true. Is this something dependent on iOS and the GPS? Can such conditions be properly handled?

Comment: A 20m limit is very small.  The best accuracy you can hope for from GPS is 10m under ideal conditions.  If you are inside or in a built-up environment you can expect GPS jitter which may be false-triggering your code.

Comment: @Paulw11 If the best accuracy is 10m, then 20m should be ok right or am i misunderstanding here? What would be the suitable value for the distance filter?

Comment: 10m is best accuracy. In a built up area like a city center gps could show you moving 40 or 50m while stationary. You could introduce an averaging algorithm to reject sudden shifts in location. You can also reject updates with low accuracy values

Comment: @Paulw11 how do I get accuracy values for location update? Or any reference to  averaging algorithm example?

Comment: You can check the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the location update. You could take the delta change in location and apply a [low pass filter](http://lukagabric.com/cmmotionmanager-and-low-pass-filter/); location updates come about once per second